# Are Business Expenses deducted against Capital Gains?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, capital-gains-tax

Suppose that you run a business in the United States that generates:

- $0 in income
- $100,000 in short-term capital gains
- $20,000 in business expenses

Normally, you can deduct expenses against your income.  But in this case, can your expenses be deducted against your capital gains?  If not, how is this handled?

Comment: How can a *business* generate *capital gains* with no income?

Comment: @littleadv This could happen in the case where assets appreciate more than the amount charged for services. A lawyer said that certain business structure themselves this way for tax efficiency.

Comment: @JoshB if you have a lawyer - why are you asking  here? Isn't it what you pay the lawyer for?

Comment: No, I don't have an attorney who's guiding me. An attorney said this in a video that I watched.

Comment: Well, then, you fell victim to one of the classic blunders, the most famous of which is "never believe an attorney in a promotional video"

Comment: An IRS form 1120 has capital gains on line 8 as part of total income. Now a company with more than 100 shareholders can have an investment portfolio, without being regulated as an investment company, if the portfolio is 60% Treasury Securities. However, the company needs a core purpose other than investment. Then consider a trading company with fewer than 100 shareholders that might be regulated as a securities-dealer. Maybe look at investment-club rules or commodity-pool rules.

Comment: @SSpring yeah, but these hardly can be characterized as "personal finance" examples... When would you have capital gains as a business income on your personal income tax return other than being a day-trader?

Comment: @SSpring I'm actually considering the question to include investment companies. Not all investment companies need to be regulated if they fall under certain exemptions. Some fees do get considered income, but other are capital gains. And if the investment manager is an LLC, they may end up with a scenario similar to the numbers posed in the original question.

Comment: Exactly, that's interesting. So in the case you described of a company that advises the partnership and receives performance fees: if their expenses exceed their income, can they continue to deduct expenses against capital gains?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, in the United States, business only generate capital gains as a by-side of their business activity. For example, you've sold a capital asset that you've been using in your business for a gain, or you invested your reserves and generated a gain.

A business that generates **only** gains is not a business, it's an investment.

For investment you can deduct some expenses, but it's limited. For example, expenses incurred prior to 2018 and exceeding 2% of your AGI can be deducted on your Schedule A for that year as an itemized deduction (this has been eliminated by TCJA, and is scheduled to return after 2025).

The only exception I can think of is being a day-trader, and for that there are [specific rules](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc429).

Comment: The concept of "carried interest" works so fund managers receive their performance fee as an allocation of assets.  Therefore their management fee will be income whereas their performance fee will be capital gains.  I'm wondering about the case of funds that charge little-to-no management fee, yet still incur significant business expenses.

Comment: @JoshB if there's little to no management fee, i.e.: little to no management, then how come such extensive short term gains? That suggest that a lot of trades occurred, or alternatively (for a fund) a quick exit, i.e.: no performance fee, only management.

Comment: I am not an expert in how funds work, but I think it is possible that a significant gain does not require many trades to occur.  And if many trades did occur, would this change the tax treatment?  You might even suppose it is long-term capital gains if that makes the question different in some way.

Comment: @JoshB you said you have an attorney who's guiding you. Why aren't you asking the attorney?

Comment: No, I don't have an attorney who's guiding me. An attorney said this in a video that I watched.

Comment: Well put - _"A business that generates only gains is not a business, it's an investment."_ is key here!